# Images of the generators of $D_{10}$ under its automorphisms.

Tags: group-theory, gap, dihedral-groups

I have constructed the dihedral group generated by $a$ and $b$ of order $10$ in GAP by the following way:

```
gap> f:=FreeGroup("a","b");
<free group on the generators [ a, b ]>
gap> g:=f/[f.1^5, f.2^2, f.2*f.1*f.2^-1*f.1];
<fp group on the generators [ a, b ]>
gap> List(g);
[ id, b, a^4*b, a, a^4, a*b, a^3*b, a^2, a^3, a^2*b ]
```

Now I need to see the automorphism group of $D_{10}$ which can be obtained by

```
gap> a:=AutomorphismGroup(g);
<group of size 20 with 3 generators>
gap> List(a);
[ IdentityMapping( <fp group of size 10 on the generators [ a, b ]> ), [ b, a ] -> Pcgs([ a*b, a ]),
  [ a, b*a^2 ] -> [ a, b ], [ a, a^2*b ] -> [ a, b ], [ a, a*b ] -> [ a, b ], [ a^-1, b ] -> [ a, b ],
  [ a^-1, a*b ] -> [ a, b ], [ a*b, a^-1 ] -> Pcgs([ a*b, a ]), [ a^-1, b*a^2 ] -> [ a, b ],
  [ a^-1, b*a ] -> [ a, b ], [ a^2, b ] -> [ a, b ], [ a^2, b*a^2 ] -> [ a, b ], [ a^2, a*b ] -> [ a, b ],
  [ a*b, a^2 ] -> Pcgs([ a*b, a ]), [ a^2, a^2*b ] -> [ a, b ], [ a^-2, b ] -> [ a, b ], [ a^-2, a^2*b ] -> [ a, b ],
  [ a^-2, b*a ] -> [ a, b ], [ a^-2, a*b ] -> [ a, b ], [ a^-2, b*a^2 ] -> [ a, b ] ]
```

Suppose I want the see the images of the generators $a$ and $b$ of $D_{10}$ under each automorphism of the group then how do I proceed?

Comment: For an automorphism `aut` the command `List(GeneratorsOfGroup(g),x->ImagesRepresentative(aut,x));` gives the images. Thus `List(a,aut->List(GeneratorsOfGroup(g),x->ImagesRepresentative(aut,x)));` does so for all automorphisms. You might want to look at the GAP manual for an introduction to this functionality.

Comment: Thank you. I got it.